# 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I am using Windows Authentication Mode/Negotiate

Server 2012R2 - IIS8.5. windows authentication and asp.Net impersonation is on
WebServer is calling an ASMX on serviceServer

In case if site is hosted on default web site (URL is http:/Test/access.apx) called the Service server asmx working fine.

But if host the website at **(http://Test/access.apx)** on same  and mapped the Domain if http://Test  to .
it opened the 1st page but calls to  is failing.
Getting following error.

### The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'

I tried wireshark intersting 
in case of URL is "http:/Test/access.apx)" its sending negotiate security data. but in case of (http://Test/access.apx) its sending NTLM security context.

Also I set the domain to 
Delegation to : "Trust this computer for delegation to any service"
than tried with SPN "Trust this account for delegation to any service"
as per
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chiranth/archive/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis.aspx

Please suggest how to pass the  windows authentication/Negotiate context to the asmx in case of non server name websites.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a **http** website (A), calling http**s** website (B), which was supposed to call back **http** website (A). But the problem was that URL address in *web.config* of B pointed to http**s**, therefore it didn't work.

So I changed binding of original website (A) to https and everything started working.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it right

Followed the steps

- Added new a new AD/service user allowed the Trusted this use to delegation to any service

--Updated SPN

setspn -s http/test Domain\serviceuser

setspn -s http/test.domain.com Domain\serviceuser

Open IIS-

Select Website

Select Authentication

-Disable Anonymous

-Enable - ASP.Net Impersonation

-Enable - Windows Authentication -

Set Providers Negotiate, NTLM

Select Website

Select ‘Configuration Editor’

Select ‘system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication’

Set 
authPersistNonNTLM to False

useAppPoolCredential to True

useKernelMode to True